# android: how to close recent activities when activities start from service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-recents

How to close recent activities(press and hold button home) when activity started from services?

Tried `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` and `android:noHistory="true"`, but it works if I close manual from `myActivity`. But, when close `finish()` from services using `Broadcast Receiver`, it doesn't work.

So, how to close recent activities when it close automatic from services?
Please help . .

Answer (score 0):

This works for clear history from recent apps:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: please add some description too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to clear the activity stack content. In API level 11 or greater, use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag on Intent to clear all the activity stack.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
// set the new task and clear flags
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(i);
```